# Why does Git ignore png files and how do I 'un-ignore' them?

Tags: git, gitignore

So I have a repo where I didn't add anything to ignore `.png` files but they are ignored anyways.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: is there a .gitignore file in the repo?

Comment: Do you have it set in a global `.gitignore` in a parent directory?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be sure if a file is ignored, and (if it is) by which .gitignore, simply use:

```
git check-ignore -v -- myfile.png
```

[`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) will display the relevant [`.gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and the relevant rule.

Answer (score 1):

It can be that you have a `/home/<user>/.gitignore_global` file which contains `*.png`. This gitignore applies to all projects on your machine. You can find this out with the command of [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905567/10452872)

Answer (score 0):

In order to start tracking previously ignored files or patterns:

1. First, you need to change your working directory to the repository by typing `cd <path>`.
2. Second, you need to specify the files or patterns to track them by typing `git add -f <file name>.extension` for a specific file or `git add -f *.png` for all png files.